# Restrict web view if it initialize once even if state gets changed

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo

I have a component which load a URL in web view and once it get loaded it redirects user to another URL/page and it does it like 4 to 5 time until user sees final page. Basically it is for OAuth flow, just to get an idea.

I want to display my custom loader component until user sees OAuth page. I have done some code with onLoadEnd and onLoadStart to manage loader visibility and web view visibility.

Like when it start loads(onLoadStart) it change state and re-render view and show loader and on end loading(onLoadEnd) it hides loader.

I have tried,
Display loader and web view based on loading state like when it is loading it shows loader, else web view. But in this when it first comes, it show web view and as soon as it starts loading it hides web view and shows loader but in this case when it hides web view it stops loading next page as it un mounts web view I think.

Display both same time but loader gets displayed only when loading is in progress but in this case when all things done it update state and it comes again to render method and loads web view again, and this goes in infinite loop.

```
render() {
        this.webview = null;
        let timeStemp = Date.parse(new Date());
        let oAuthUrl = `https://www.oAuthUrl.com`;
        return (
            <View style={[styles.mainContainerOuter]}>
                {this.props.authIsLoading == true ?
                    <Loader modelVisibility={this.props.authIsLoading}></Loader>
                    : null}
                <WebView
                    ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
                    key={timeStemp}
                    source={{ uri: oAuthUrl }}
                    cacheEnabled={false}
                    style={stylesSelf.webView}
                    domStorageEnabled={false}

                    thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={false}
                    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
                    incognito={true}
                    sharedCookiesEnabled={false}
                    startInLoadingState
                    onLoadEnd={() => {
                        this.loaderTimeStemp = setTimeout(() => {
                            this.props.manageAuthLoader(false);
                        }, 1000);
                        console.log('onLoadEnd');
                    }}
                    onLoadStart={() => {
                        console.log('onLoadStart');
                        if (this.props.authIsLoading != true) this.props.manageAuthLoader(true);
                        if (this.loaderTimeStemp) clearTimeout(this.loaderTimeStemp);
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

I am expecting like once loads completed and user reach at OAuth page it should hide loader only and not reloads web view.